# What are ways to avoid an big N-gon when modeling stairs?

Tags: modeling, topology

I tried different approaches, I still want the Bevel modifier to work, but can't find a solution. I want it be flexible, so without a lot of tris.
Once I fill it, the bevel stops working, even when I try to merge everything by distance.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a single easiest way, but here are two that both work:

1. model the side rail as a separate object:  In your example you could make it one big rectangle.  Any possible Z fighting will be hidden by the rail, and you can delete the faces of the stairs that wouldn't be visible.
2. If you must have the two bits in one model, grid fill the side rail to make polygons.